# Inno Setup: Create link in the StartUp folder to a Jetty Launcher placed in Program Files (x86)

Tags: jetty, inno-setup

I wrote a script with Inno Setup which installs a Jetty with some web applications.
The user can choose the installation directory, and after that, a link to the `Launcher.exe` file is created in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` to allow Jetty to start automatically when Windows starts.

Here the code:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Wr Addon
AppVersion=1.0
AppPublisher=Hitachi Systems CBT S.p.A.  
;the default directory where program is installed
UninstallDisplayName=Wr Addon
;give to the use the chance to choose the install directory
DisableDirPage=no  
DefaultDirName=WrAddon
;the directory where is placed the uninstaller, the path the destination dir choosed by the user with the uninstall subdirectory
UninstallFilesDir={app}\uninstall

[Setup]
;Request to restart the system after to install the program. 
AlwaysRestart = yes  

[Files]
Source: "jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs

;create a link to the Launcher.exe in the StartUp directory of Windows 
[Icons] 
Name: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\Launcher.exe; Filename: "{app}\Launcher.exe"

;run the stop.bat file during the uninstall phase to close the Java tasks and allow to delete the program folder
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\stop.bat"; Parameters: "/x"; Flags: waituntilterminated

;delete all files and directories (also new file created during the jetty execution)
[UninstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\*"; 
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}"

[Code]
const LINKPATH = 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\Launcher.lnk';


//procedure DeinitializeSetup();
//var
//  ShortcutPath: string;
//begin
//  ShortcutPath := CreateShellLink(LINKPATH, 'Shortcut to Launcher.exe', ExpandConstant('{app}\Launcher.exe'), '', LINKPATH, '', 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
//  MsgBox('shortcut created in '+ShortcutPath, mbInformation, MB_OK);                 
//end;
```

The installer creates properly the link if the installation directory is not `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`
Note that I tried to create link following two ways:

- with `[Icons]`
- with `CreateShellLink` (commented)

The behavior is the same.
If I placed the installation in other directories (for example the `Desktop` or in `C:\`) it works fine.
I doubt that there are some problems about admin permissions, because if the installation directory is not `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`, when I reboot Windows, Jetty starts properly.

If the directory installation is `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`, Jetty doesn't start after to reboot Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? Is the shortcut not created? Or is it not working? Your `[Icons]` entry works for me (creates the shortcut).

Comment: Just note that you should not hard-code the path, use `{commonprograms}`. + The shortcut should not have a name `Launcher.exe`. Give it a meaningful name.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl when I reboot Windows, if the installation directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files` the Java processes about Jetty don't start. The shortcut is always properly created and point to the correct file.

Comment: And if you run the shortcut manually?

Comment: What if you install to another directory with a space in the name? Would it work?

Comment: Can you even run the `Launcher.exe` directly, when it is installed in "Program Files"?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if I run the shortcut manually doesn't work.
If I run the `Launcher.exe` file without Administrator permissions doenst' work, whereas If I run it with administrator permission works.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If I install to another directory with space in the name it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105123/discussion-between-milioli-luca-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 0):

As you found yourself the `Launcher.exe` does not work at all when installed to "Program Files" unless it is run with Administrator privileges.

It most probably needs write permissions to its installation folder.

So there's nothing wrong with the shortcut. You just cannot install the `Launcher.exe` to a directory where the user does not have a write access to.

Maybe there's some configuration option that can make the `Launcher.exe` write the files, it needs, to a different directory than it is installed to.